# How to map unique values in column to indices in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the [worldcitiespop.txt.gz](https://github.com/CODAIT/redrock/tree/master/twitter-decahose/src/main/resources/Location) database. What I need to do is take the Country column, which has 2-letter strings for all the country codes, and map every unique code to an index (in no particular order).

Input:

> us ca nl us nl

Output:

> 0 1 2 0 2

Currently I attempt to do this using:

```
cities['Country-id'] = cities['Country'].map(pd.Series(cities.Country.unique()))
```

Sampling 10 rows gives us:
[image: Output table]

What am I doing wrong? Why are all the values in the new column NaN?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
cities['Country-id'] = pd.factorize(cities['Country'])[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
cities['Country-id'] = cities.groupby('Country').ngroup()
```